# Error compiling Cython file: pxd not found in package

Tags: cython

Trying to cimport pxd definitions from other packages.

Simple example, a.pxd file:

```
cdef inline void a():
    print "a"
```

b.pyx file:

```
cimport a

def b():
    a.a()
```

Until here, everything is ok, and `$ cython b.pyx` works.

If i move a.pxd to a folder, e.g `libs/`, then I change b.pyx to:

```
from libs cimport a

def b():
    a.a()
```

and then I have the error:

```
$ cython b.pyx 

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from libs cimport a
^
------------------------------------------------------------

b.pyx:1:0: 'a.pxd' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from libs cimport a
^
------------------------------------------------------------

b.pyx:1:0: 'libs/a.pxd' not found
```

But libs/a.pxd is there.
What would be the right way to import pxd definitions from other packages?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[A directory is not a package unless it contains a `__init__.py` file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages), even if the file is empty. So add an empty `__init__.py` file to the `libs` directory.

---

With this directory structure, your `a.pxd` and `b.pyx`, `setup.py` and `script.py` (below),

```
% tree .
.
├── libs
│   ├── a.pxd
│   └── __init__.py
├── b.c
├── b.pyx
├── b.so
├── build
│   ├── temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
│   │   └── b.o
│   └── temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
│       └── b.o
├── script.py
├── setup.py
```

Running `script.py` works:

```
% python setup.py build_ext --inplace
% python ./script.py 
a
```

---

setup.py:

```
# python setup.py build_ext --inplace

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='test',
    ext_modules=cythonize("b.pyx"),
)
```

---

script.py:

```
import b
b.b()
```

Comment: This is the first thing you should check when any `.pxd` file is not found by any other cython file. Great!

Comment: I would upvote again if I could, I just ran into this issue again (facepalm)